# PasswordSignInAsync returns always failed

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

In *ApplicationDBContext.cs* I have added the following code to seed the test user login information.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS");var hasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(new ApplicationUser
    {
        Id = "1",
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith",
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        UserName = "john.smith@example.com",
        NormalizedUserName = "John Smith",
        Email = "john.smith@example.com",
        NormalizedEmail = "john.smith@example.com",
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        LockoutEnabled = false,
        PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "A1234%6789"),
    });
}
```

In the *UserController.cs* in the login function I have the following line of code that logs the user based on username and password combination.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("john.smith@example.com", "A1234%6789", false, false);
```

However the value of result is always failed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to use the following lines of code and make changes to your code accordingly.

```
//Get the matched email user details
var SingleUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.Email);

var verfiyPassword = _userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(SingleUser, SingleUser.PasswordHash, model.Password);

//If the verification failed.
if (verfiyPassword != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
{

}

//If the verification success.
if (verfiyPassword == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
{

}
```